# how to give space between bootstrap columns

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

am using bootstrap 5 , am creating 6 column in a row where i have used gutter in row, but gutter is not applying on it, i am not able to see space between columns. can anyone guide me what am doing wrong here? following is my code

---

```
.box{
    height: 100px;
    background-color: blue;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.myrow{
    background-color: red;
}
<div class="container">
     <div class="row myrow gx-5">
        
        <div class="box col-lg-2">1</div>
        <div class="box col-lg-2">2</div>
        <div class="box col-lg-2">3</div>
        <div class="box col-lg-2">4</div>
        <div class="box col-lg-2">5</div>
        <div class="box col-lg-2">6</div>
        
     </div>

 </div>
```

Comment: What do u want to achive exactly? I mean, each row is separated correctly with enough spaces. [Here](https://codepen.io/Szabii97/pen/oNWqOZd) is a link for your example.

Comment: @NagySzabolcs actually am trying to fit image in column and then give space between all columns so my images looks separate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want images in columns but make some space between the columns so pictures won't collide.

If you don't want to use paddings, you can always use margins. In bootstrap, you can give **ml-1, ml-2** classes (until 5) which can make margins for you.

> ml -> margin-left

> mr -> margin-right

Here is a simple example based on your code, I hope it helps!

```css
.box{
    height: 100px;
    background-color: blue;
    box-sizing: border-box; 
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px;
}
.myrow{
    background-color: red;
}

img {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
     <div class="row myrow gx-5">
        
        <div class="box col-lg-2"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/8nKVc0s.jpg"></div>
        <div class="box col-lg-2"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/8nKVc0s.jpg"></div>
        <div class="box col-lg-2"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/8nKVc0s.jpg"></div>
        <div class="box col-lg-2"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/8nKVc0s.jpg"></div>
        <div class="box col-lg-2"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/8nKVc0s.jpg"></div>
        <div class="box col-lg-2"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/8nKVc0s.jpg"></div>
        
     </div>

 </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Using your code, I've found that the gutters are working as intended. Maybe you aren't seeing this because you are applying the background color to the columns, not the column containers. See below for more.
https://codepen.io/QuiteQuinn/pen/JjNLVbO

[image]

```
.box{
    height: 100px;
    background-color: blue;
}
.myrow{
    background-color: red;
}
span{
    width: 100%;
    background: yellow;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row myrow gx-5">
    <div class="box col-lg-2"> <span>1</span></div>
    <div class="box col-lg-2"> <span>2</span></div>
    <div class="box col-lg-2"> <span>3</span></div>
    <div class="box col-lg-2"> <span>4</span></div>
    <div class="box col-lg-2"> <span>5</span></div>
    <div class="box col-lg-2"> <span>6</span></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: gutters are not for spacing between columns ? i means space between column 1 and column 2 not space between their content ?

Comment: Thats the way gutters work in Bootstrap

Comment: To clarify, gutters are for the space between columns, but this space is created with padding and padding is included in the background of an element. This means that when you apply a blue background to the background of an element with padding.. the padding will also show as blue.

Comment: @QuinnKeaveney so is there anyway to create space between columns and padding 0 inside its column ? actually am trying to fit image in column and then give space between all columns so my images looks separate

Comment: If you place images in the column then that intended effect should work. See here. https://codepen.io/QuiteQuinn/pen/JjNLVbO

Comment: The scenario where that wouldn't work would be if you are placing images as backgrounds... if that's the case place them within a div inside of the column.